# Maximal family of cycles in directed 3-regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Consider a finite directed 3-regular graph $G=(V,E)$ where $(v,w)\in E$ implies also that $(w,v)\in E$. I am looking for a maximal set $\mathcal{C}$ of simple cycles of length greater of equal $3$ such that every edge of the graph is traversed exactly once. The set $\mathcal{C}$ should be maximal in the sense that any other $\mathcal{C}'$ satisfying the same condition also satisfies $|\mathcal{C}'|\leq |\mathcal{C}|$. It seems like a computationally hard problem (NP) but does someone have an idea how to approach this or how to connect it to a known problem?

I first thought of an approach via cycle basis but then I could not find a definition of cycle basis for directed graphs. A computational approach via Johnson's algorithm (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2794683) for details) to build an idea also led nowhere.

Comment: An affirmative answer of this question will led to an answer to the [Cycle double cover conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_double_cover).

Comment: Potentially, yes, but it seems that my version is weaker in that you might go back and forth between two vertices over the course of a simple cycle as first and last edge. But maybe such cycles can never be part of a maximal family.